# Can any one explain me about self-join in oracle with simple example?

Tags: self-join

Can any one explain me about self-join in oracle with simple example.i have searched in many sites but i couldn't understand..

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have employee table

```
  ID NAME MANAGER_ID
   1 Andy 10
   2 Bill 10
   3 Chaz 11
  10 Joy  12
  11 Kath 12
  12 Lois (null)
```

And you want to select someone and their manager.

```
  SELECT FROM EMPLOYEE PERSON, EMPLOYEE MANAGER WHERE EMPLOYEE.MANAGER_ID = MANAGER.ID
```

So the key idea is that we are using the EMPLOYEE table in two ways, to find people, and to find managers.

This probably doesn't fully explain what you want to know, maybe you could now explain in more detail what you don't understand.